# Deploying a Keras model with cloudml on RStudio fails

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras, google-cloud-ml

I'm trying to deploy my trained keras model on Google Cloud ML. The model works fine on my local machine, but it fails to deploy in cloud. I'm working with the cloudml library on RStudio on a macOS High Sierra (10.13.4).

Here's a toy example:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential()

model %>%
  layer_dense(units = 78, activation = "sigmoid", input_shape = c(39)) %>%
  layer_dense(units = 39, activation = "sigmoid") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 20, activation = "sigmoid") %>%
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid") %>% 
  compile(
    loss = 'mean_squared_error',
    optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(),
    metrics = c('mean_squared_error')
  )

history <- model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  epochs = 1000,
  validation_split = 0.2
)

# deploy
export_savedmodel(model, "model")
cloudml_deploy("model", name = "keras_model")
```

Here's my version info:

```
> R.Version()
$platform
[1] "x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0"

$arch
[1] "x86_64"

$os
[1] "darwin15.6.0"

$system
[1] "x86_64, darwin15.6.0"   

$status
[1] ""

$major
[1] "3"

$minor
[1] "4.1"

$year
[1] "2017"

$month
[1] "06"

$day
[1] "30"

$`svn rev`
[1] "72865" 

$language
[1] "R"

$version.string
[1] "R version 3.4.1 (2017-06-30)"

$nickname
[1] "Single Candle"
```

My RStudio is Version 1.1.423. Local R libraries versions are:

```
cloudml: 0.5
keras: 2.1.6.9001
tensorflow: 1.5.0.9001
```

The error message I get is

```
Creating version (this might take a few minutes)
..............................................
..............................................
..............................................
..............................................
..............................................
...........................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.ml-engine.versions.create) Bad model 
detected with error:  "Failed to load model: Loading 
servable: {name: default version: 1} failed: Not found: 
Op type not registered 'ClipByValue' in binary running 
on localhost. Make sure the Op and Kernel are registered 
in the binary running in this process.\n\n (Error code: 0
```

Any idea of what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In the `cloudml` R package, to use TensorFlow 1.8, you can set the `cloudml.yml` to:

`trainingInput:
  runtimeVersion: 1.8`

Then deploy as usual `cloudml_deploy("model", name = "keras_model")` to deploy using the TensorFlow 1.8 runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the graph is produced on a newer version of TensorFlow which includes the `ClipByValue` op (1.8+), but consumed on an older version which doesn't. The easiest solution would be to use a newer version of TensorFlow for deployment, but potentially you could generate the graph with an older TensorFlow version (before 1.8).

Comment: Very good, thank you! Is there a preferred way of setting the CloudML tensor flow version for a model via the R cloudml package?

Comment: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tensorflow/articles/installation.html#custom-installation seems to indicate you can manually install the Python TensorFlow package, then just point the R bindings to it. Sounds promising?

Comment: That's right and for other people who could find a similar error, this was a common error for a while as per: https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/924 or https://github.com/migueldeicaza/TensorFlowSharp/issues/276

Answer (score 0):

When you create the version, specify the flag `--runtime-version=1.8`

Comment: I'm creating the version using the `cloudml::cloudml_deploy` function. However, trying to pass the runtimeVersion flag as `cloudml_deploy("model", name = "keras_model", config = list(runtimeVersion=1.8))` does not work, either.

Comment: @LauriLovén I think you're on the right track with using `config`, but since I'm not familiar with this library, I'm not 100% sure what the appropriate syntax would be. I presume in JSON it would be {"runtimeVersion": "1.8"}